# Ubuntu 14.04 does not have Keyboard in All Settings

Tags: keyboard, system-settings

All Settings contains:

- language support
- Security privacy
- Printers
- Landscape service
- Software & Updates

but I don't have "keyboard". Why?

Comment: Please, provide more information about your hardware (PC model/keyboard model). If possible also add a screenshot and state if this is a recent problem, that is, have you used Ubuntu before without this problem (and with the same hardware)?

Comment: Does `dpkg -l gkbd-capplet` say whether it's installed?